# Cant play multiplayer , servers wont come up on minecraft pe

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I cant join my sisters server on minecraft pe without both of us turning our Ipads off and on . Her server does not come up on my minecraft. Our multiplayer and LAN is on too , our wifi is also working.Please help.

Comment: Can anyone help ?????

Answer (score 1):

both of you should be able to click the home button then click it twice so you can see your recent apps then scroll up on minecraft pocket edition then go back into it and it should work that happened to me one time and that solved it for me.